# Apache commons math PolynomialSolver: how to get all roots?

Tags: java, polynomial-math, apache-commons-math

Hi basic question in trying to use commons-math's PolynomialSolver classes.

According to the documentation here http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/analysis.html as well as the API the solving methods typically take the form

```
double c = solver.solve(100, function, 1.0, 5.0, AllowedSolution.LEFT_SIDE);
```

I'm obviously missing something, but given that the fundamental theorem of algebra is that there are n roots for a polynomial of n degree, how do I get all the roots?

What good is a root solver returning one double?

I noticed in this thread [Finding roots of polynomial in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805644/finding-roots-of-polynomial-in-java) that the method offered in the solutions returns a complex array. This is what I'd expect, so could someone kindly explain why the commons-math polynomial solvers are returning one double root?

Comment: I see that in 3.1 there was added a SolveAllComplex option for the LaguerreSolver .  I would still be interested to know if it is correct that most methods only solve for one double however, and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most of these numerical algorithms operate on generic functions (i.e. not necessarily polynomials) and make few assumptions about them. if we don't know what given function's nature exactly is, we can't even expect to infer how many roots it might have.

some algorithms there make additional assumptions that given functions are differentiable. this makes them faster but require you to provide some additional info like derivate value so you can't use them for any function anymore.

LaguerreSolver makes additional assumption that given function is a polynomial. is this case it is possible to find all roots, hence solveAllComplex() method. but it is the only algorithm there specialized in polynomials. all the other algorithms are far more generic.

Comment: Thanks very much. Testing the Laguerre so far the solveAll either hangs or is taking an extremely long time, while the solve for one solution produces nearly the same value every time, with some variation below the 6th decimal place or so. Just wondering if you can think of an obvious reason why it would do this?

Comment: variations come fron numerical instability I suppose. to find other roots using one-solution approach you have to guess sufficently narrow intervals for each root first and only then run solve() for these intervals. if commons-math runs too slow, perhaps you might look for another library: http://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/wiki/PolynomialRootExample or http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Polynomial.html