# Polynomials java library

Tags: java, api, polynomial-math

I was wondering is there an API for polynomials in java with multiple variables, for example f(x,y,z). The main functionality required is solving the equation with multiple variables, and adding and subtracting two polynomials.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The [commons math library](http://commons.apache.org/math/) can do that.

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805644/finding-roots-of-polynomial-in-java).

Comment: can you please specify how common math library can do that? I can't seem to find the required class for my problem. The only thing I can find on apache site is [PolynomialFunction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/polynomials/PolynomialFunction.html) for one variable polynomial.

Comment: It seems you are right. It does not seem to support multivariate polynomials yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some choices according to your project needs:

1. [open source physics](http://www.opensourcephysics.org/)
2. [commons math library](http://commons.apache.org/math/)
3. [Polynomial Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/92symbolic/Polynomial.java.html)