# How to get all three roots from a cube root function in Java 8

Tags: java, complex-numbers

I have to do (-5.428271)<sup>1/3</sup> and want the complex-number "0.8787335 + 1.522011i" as well as the other 2 results.

Is there a method to do that?

If there isn't, how can I create it?

Comment: you can find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805644/finding-roots-of-polynomial-in-java

Comment: just jive 0's to other coefficients your problem is done

Comment: Using a polynomial roots solver seems to be a bit of an overkill.

Comment: Why not just computing `(5.428271) ^ 1/3` * `e^(2 ik pi/3)`? (where k = 0,1 or 2)

Answer (score 1):

[Apache commons math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) has an [nthRoot](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/complex/Complex.html#nthRoot(int)) method returning a list of complex values. If you do not want the dependency, the javadoc has the formula.